# How to configure SonarQube server so that it can access another node?

Tags: linux, jenkins, sonarqube

I am running a SonarQube server on a node (lets say 10.4.1.206). On another node (10.1.4.0.96), I am running Jenkins with Sonar plugin. I also installed PDF Plugin on SonarQube server so that everytime an analysis completes, the results will be exported as PDF.

The problem is, I ran the analysis on Jenkins, which is on a different node than SonarQube server. The analysis went fine and are published on the SonarQube server. However, once the PDF report has generated, I cannot access the report from the SonarQube dashboard. My guess is that SonarQube cannot connect to the node which is hosting Jenkins. (That is where the PDF report is stored).

So my question is, is there anyway to configure SonarQube so that it has permissions to connect to another node?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? It was probably related to SonarQube and PDF Report versions compatibility.

Comment: No I ended up writing my own script to export results.

Comment: If you are still using the plugin and want to solve the issue, I'll be happy to help. What SonarQube and PDF Report versions are you using?

Comment: Thank you, however I am attending school at the moment. This question occurred during a company internship I had over the summer, so I don't remember much of the details. If you really want to resolve this issue, I can try and dig up the details. If not, then I should probably close this question.